# Gearbox singing at 6th gear

Tags: noise, manual-transmission, hyundai, elantra

I'm driving a Hyundai Elantra 2012 manual model and when I change into 6th gear and apply any pressure on the accelerator, I get a high pitched singing sound.  It's completely clear whatever I do in 5th gear and below, and if I'm in 6th gear and coasting downhill it's fine, but as soon as I accelerate, whether uphill or downhill, it starts to sing.

Any ideas? And how serious could it be?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but would assume a bearing is probably going out in your transmission. The bearing would have to be on the carrier for 6th gear. I'm not at all aware of the makeup of how your transmission is put together, so this is just a stab in the dark. You'll probably want to have a transmission shop take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm also reading up that gears can become noisy when an oil change is due, but in my mind that doesn't explain why only 6th gear is out.

Comment: i would agree with you about it only being 6th gear which is noisy and not think it being a gear oil issue.